# Shape error with a CNN on a Batch Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a convolutional neural network i Python.
I have imported the libraries tensorflow and keras and loaded the convolutional layers weights of vgg16, creating a neaural network suitable for classifinig input images of shape (128,128,3) into 5 classes.
Here is the summary of the neural network:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
vgg16 (Functional)           (None, 4, 4, 512)         14714688  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 8192)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 5)                 40965     
=================================================================
Total params: 14,755,653
Trainable params: 40,965
Non-trainable params: 14,714,688
```

the problem is that when I try to run it with a dataset loaded by

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width))
```

altought everything seems fine, since i get the message

```
Found 3670 files belonging to 5 classes.
```

I get an error in the training

```
---> 47 model.fit(train_ds,epochs=10,batch_size=5)
ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 5) are incompatible
```

I don't know what to do: where does (None,1) comes from? What should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation for [`tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory#arguments), namely for the `label_mode` argument. Since you didn't specify the argument, it defaults to `'int'`, and so it will return values like `[1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1]`, with shape `(None, 1)`. This will confuse Keras when it compares your logits with shape `(None, 5)` with loss [`tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy).

Do this and it should work:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  label_mode='categorical',
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width))
```

Or, instead of using loss [`tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy), use [`tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy).

Here's the info from the link I gave:

> ***label_mode:***
> **'int'**: means that the labels are encoded as integers (e.g. for sparse_categorical_crossentropy loss). **'categorical'** means that the labels are encoded as a categorical vector (e.g. for categorical_crossentropy loss). **'binary'** means that the labels (there can be only 2) are encoded as float32 scalars with values 0 or 1 (e.g. for binary_crossentropy).
> None (no labels).

Answer (score 1):

You should take a closer look at the return values of `image_dataset_from_directory` and the input parameters to `fit`.

The documentation of `image_dataset_from_directory` says `label_mode='int'` is the default value and that a tuple is returned in that case (which is your somewhat hidden target label parameter `y` in the `fit` call), so I would suggest to do the following:

```
train_images, train_labels = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
```

Then you can check out the shape of `train_labels`. To solve the problem, as Nicolas already said, use `label_mode='categorical'`. Make sure to use Softmax activation in your final layer in that case, since the labels will be one-hot encoded, i.e. this will be a classification problem.

Comment: Although the docs say that if label_mode is not None "it yields a tuple (images, labels),", I get `too many values to unpack (expected 2)` if I use it like this, any idea why?